# pandas: aggregate to keep first non-NaN value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with `test_num` as index:

```
file_num    6    7
test_num          
79        NaN    ↑
148         ↑  NaN
```

I need to reduce it to keep a first available direction (arrow) for any `file_num`:

```
           direction
test_num          
79          ↑
148         ↑
```

I've tried this:

```
fd.agg(lambda x: [a for a in x if a][0], axis=1)

test_num
79     NaN
148      ↑

fd.agg(lambda x: [a for a in x if a != pd.np.nan][0], axis=1)

test_num
79     NaN
148      ↑
```

How to do what I need here?

Comment: df.bfill() in the duplicated answer is genius.  Here's what I was typing in when this was closed, which you might need in case you have to modify the specification going forward: `df.T.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().head(1)).fillna('').sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a uniform array in a `groupby`

```
df.groupby([*'A'*len(df.columns)], 1).first()

          A
test_num   
79        ↑
148       ↑
```

---

Or use a callable to the same effect

```
df.groupby(lambda x: 'A', 1).first()

          A
test_num   
79        ↑
148       ↑
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X = X.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis = 1)

        1.0
test_num    
79        ↑
148       ↑
```